# I don't get it S + Verb + Verb +고싶어!! : "말해 보고싶어"

Tags: grammar

While trying to understand a Korean lyric, i was faced with this strange case, were the desire expression "고싶어" is preceded by 2 verbs, ex :

> **말해** **보**고싶어
>   나 **불러** **보**고싶어

So i want to see what exactly ?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, there's an expression '*see if* you can do something', which means that you're going to try to do it.

The expression *어/아 보다' in Korean is similar - it means *to try* to do something.

So 어/아 보고싶다 is *to want to try* to do something.

> 말해 보고싶어 - I want to try and say it / I want to try to tell (something to someone). 
>   나 불러 보고싶어 - I want to try calling.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any grammatical form for this.

Comment: @habibhassani from your question, it seems that you already know that the grammatical form **-고싶다** means 'want', and in my answer I've said that **-어/아 보다** is a grammatical form meaning 'to try'. [Korean Grammar for International Leaners](https://www.amazon.com/Korean-Grammar-International-Learners-Bin/dp/8971415541) calls it a 시도의 보조용인 - an exploratory auxiliary verb. I think those are the only grammatical forms common to both your example sentences.